# How to optimize a large graph for pathfinding algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I develop a small program where an user can create a simple diagrams with abstract blocks connected by lines, for example, flow charts or structural diagrams. One of the clause of the statement of work is that lines have to get around other blocks\lines and don't intersect them while moving.

Illustration

[image]

I tried to use pathfinding algorithms like **A*** or **Lee's algorithm** for it and consider a workspace (a window with diagram elements) like a graph - one pixel is one graph node. However, moving of blocks\lines causes the significant time delay (for example, pathfinding in the workspace with size **500x500** takes about **320-360 ms**). It seems like the graph is too big for those algorithms.

Could you please tell me how to reduce the number of nodes with regard to this case? Maybe is there a way to speed up those algorithms or use something other for it?!

Comment: `one pixel is one graph node` - this is your problem.  There must be a way to make it less granular.  I don't quite understand your problem so I can't say exactly how.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft As far as I know, I can't make the grid (the graph of workspace is considered as a grid here) more granular because the minimum size of a obstacle is 1x1 (part of line between blocks)

Comment: Maybe Jump Point Search? It is good at large open areas

Comment: Can the blocks intersect? Correct me if I'm wrong but there might be much simpler solution to your problem. If blocks can't intersect and user moves one block then the path he created by moving the block could be a line connecting two blocks. Else try, there are some tools predefined for this purpose mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459919/what-are-some-good-algorithms-for-drawing-lines-between-graph-nodes

Comment: @lucky125111 Block can intersect each other. Yup, if an user moves a block (connected to other block), the line between blocks is drawn without intersection any blocks and lines.

Comment: What happens if user moves one block inside different block? The line is removed? I'm trying to understand the problem more, cause it seems to be pretty complex if you dont use external library

Comment: @lucky125111 In this case line would be created by the same pathfinding algorithm but without any obstacles (blocks, lines) on the grid. Like there are only two blocks and lines between them on the workspace. It doesn't matter right now TBH, the main task is which algorithm to use and how to optimize the graph.

Comment: By the way you aren't pre-creating nodes for all pixels, are you? It's a relatively common mistake that would waste a massive amount of time in the likely case that not all pixels need to be considered by the path search

Comment: This sort of question could do with example image(s), even if they're just quick sketches in MS Paint.

Comment: @harold Right now I use Lee's algorithm without nodes - it uses an 1-byte array representing the workspace grid so accessing to cells has to be fast. When I used A* algorithm, nodes were created by demand.

Comment: Your main issue is really the 1 node per pixel setup. Your graph is huge. For real, I worked with creating google-map-like algorithms on real world data. My full street graph for whole Europe only contained like 10 million nodes, consuming about 100 GB RAM in total, taking about 100ms with a regular A*-Dijkstra (which isnt really a very good algorithm anyways). The final algorithm took around 20ms. Anyways, my point is that your graphs easily get much larger than whole Europe and people struggled long for solving those sizes and you probably dont have 100 GB RAM on your private machine.

Comment: This approach is flawed already, take a different. You could also for example easily improve on your situation without changing your overall approach by dividing your huge large white open areas into bigger rectangles. Like, why do you have to keep a 1 node per pixel setup in those areas? You dont. Just interpret the full area as one big node that spans a full rectangle area. You can do that in a preparation phase and then your graph size reduces from maybe millions of nodes to just 1k nodes or so.

Answer (score 3):

Don't think of this as a graph theory problem, think of it as a physics problem.

Visualize it as follows.  Each block has a specified force pulling it towards the last place that it was put.  Line segments, blocks, and the edge of the graph repel each other with an inverse square law (except that the end of the line you are drawing doesn't repel blocks in front of it). Under sufficient stress, a line segment can be broken into smaller line segments that have a pull towards returning to being a straight line.

The dynamics are complicated, but the number of entities is the number of objects you see on screen, not the number of pixels it is drawn on.  Therefore you'll be able to do updates relatively quickly.

You'll need to play with the dynamics a bit to get a good experience, but this should be a more tractable approach.